# Use preexisting RSA SSH keys to decrypt a text in C#

Tags: c#, encryption, rsa, bouncycastle, openssh

I have a pair of RSA public/private keys generated by the 'ssh-keygen' command in a Linux computer. There is a Ruby application in this Linux computer that encrypts a string using this public key, and I want to use this private key to decrypt the string in a Windows C#/.Net application. I took a look at the Bouncy Castle libs, without success. Any example or tip would be helpful. Thanks!

Comment: RSA keys in SSH are only used to sign data to validate identities, not to encrypt session data or even exchange session keys.  Using them to encrypt data is not exactly a best practice.

Answer (score -3):

Is there reason to use ssh keys?

Any RSA key would suffice. You need to extract RSA key to encrypt anything. And if that key is not RSA, you cannot encrypt anything, as DSA is signature only algorithm. There is RFC for public keys: http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4716.txt It is not exactly what you need. But may help you understand how to extract each part. It should be only base64 encoded binary chunks.

You can try PuTTY source http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html
keygen can generate and convert those keys. So, if you find place where it extracts RSA key. Then use any crypto library to compute RSA using keys and data. With correct keys, you will get input data + padding. Depends whether public or private key were used by ruby program. Hope that helps.

Comment: Because I prefer to use open standards. My Ruby code (http://pastebin.com/1djhPRxN) works perfectly both ways (encrypt and decrypt). I would like to have the same results with my C#/.Net code.